# 'Unknown template type' when importing using Content Porter

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-porter-2013

I exported the DXA '000 Empty Master' publication from a UAT CM and received the following error message upon attempted import on PRD:

```
Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ProblemDiscoveredException: Unknown template type: /webdav/000%20Empty%20Master/Building%20Blocks/System/Tridion%20Defaults/Default%20Template%20Building%20Block.tbbs.
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.UnknownTemplateTypeDetector.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Detect>b__2()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Process.<>c__DisplayClass2.<InvokeInErrorHandler>b__1(Boolean isRetry)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.InteractiveErrorHandler.Invoke[T](Func`2 function, LocalizableMessage message, Boolean retryAvailable, Boolean isCritical, UserReply additionalUserReplyOptions)
```

UAT is a Tridion 2013 SP1 install with DXA installed, publishing and running correctly
PRD is a clean Tridion 2013 SP1 install with the 'Tridion Reference Implementation.xml' copied into the 'ApplicationData' folder as directed in the documentation.

Anyone know how to resolve this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error would indicate that your UAT environment has Tridion's legacy pack installed and that the export of your 000 Empty Master publication contains some templates/TBBs based on the deprecated legacy template types (VBScript/JScript).

Your PRD environment most likely doesn't have the legacy pack installed, and thus does not understand what the templates you exported from the UAT system are.

You could delete those older templates if you're not using them, or you could install the legacy features onto your PRD environment by running the Content Manager Server installer from the command line with an extra `LEGACY_VISIBLE=TRUE` key-value pair (as per the [online docs](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-33187D11-0B59-4ABB-A67E-C448FD952F04))

Comment: Indeed! Thanks David. Side note: If legacy pack is installed the template type of the 'Default Template Building Block' defaults to VBScript. If not installed it defaults to 'Compound Template'. This threw me off because I could see that both UAT + PRD had managed to create a default template without realising that they were of different types.